# Do I need a visa if I travel from Paris to Amsterdam if I entered as Crew Member?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, saudi-citizens

I am going to Paris for two days visit as a crew member so I won't need a visa to enter France since I am registered in the general declaration (GenDec). Anyway, I have a friend in Amsterdam whom I would like to visit. I want to go to Amsterdam in the morning by train and come back at night. Do I need a visa? Are there immigration checkpoints? 
I can make Schengen visa but I need at least 9 days and I am leaving tomorrow!

**Edit: GenDec**

IF you do not know what is the "General Declaration (GenDec or GD)" it is a form that has all names of crew members on-board an aircraft/ship which is issued by the carrier and has to be signed by the crew members and will be handled to the immigration authority at the destination. This GenDec will grant the access to the crew members. Most countries will allow the crew to access just by the GenDec (Including Europe) some requires crew to have their own crew visas (USA, China...).

Comment: We might need to know what nationality / passport / residency you have to answer this - but you might not have much chance I'm afraid...

Comment: @hippietrail I have an Arabian Passport.

Comment: Hopefully somebody will have a definite answer for you soon thanks HaLaBi! (-:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some inspection and asking few crew members. It turns out that if you enter any country within the Schengen area as a crew member then you can move within the Schengen area. Make sure you have your passport and a copy of the crew members General Declaration.

**UPDATE:**

I went to Amsterdam and came back, I asked the police at the station in Paris and he said it's ok. Anyway no one stopped me or asked me. All went smooth just like a domestic trip.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what a general declaration is, but chances are you won't be allowed to travel outside the issuing country. To travel around in the Schengen area you generally need a Schengen visa (or be a citizen of a Schengen country).

This being said, there is of course the option of just going anyway. There are no routine checks at borders within the Schengen area anymore (except in some special cases like the European football championship 2008 where Austria did check passports at the border). I went to the Czech Republic twice without bringing my passport or any other valid form of ID (I'm from a neighboring country; driving license probably won't be accepted). There were no checks at the border and it's quite unlikely that police will randomly check your passport and visa - but it could happen anywhere and anytime of course!

Comment: You should probably find out what happens to you if they do catch you...since I'm a European citizen, I'm pretty sure nothing much would happen to me, but I guess you'd be sent home immediately and quite probably will have difficulties to enter the Schengen area again.

Comment: True, there are no border checks in the Schengen area. However, the French police is patroling routinely on international trains to France. If you have an arabic appearance, you will be controlled for sure.

Comment: And the France police will pretty sure look for drugs as well.